# Mass of "orange" in 25% orange juice

Tags: molecules, concentration

Hypothetical question: 
Knowing that orange juice has `25%` concentration of orange. And knowing mass of juice which is `200g`. What is mass of oranges included in juice?

Assuming that orange is a molecule, am I right that mass in 25% juice would be `25% x 200g = 50gram`?

I am thinking about simple formulas, without mols on basic level. 
If I know mass of entire liquid and know that 25% of acid is a concentration, so do I have to simply computer percentage, or rather computing for acid and rest differently?

Comment: No. Molecular mass doesn't change with concentration alteration. (Your question is sounding a little bit wierd to me)

Comment: Are you asking how many grams of a molecule in orange juice would be expected from 25% juice? Perhaps with the assumption that the juice is made up of the same compound?

Comment: @Melanie Shebel, it sounded like that was what was being asked at first. That's not what's being asked now.

Answer (score 3):

If the mass of the juice is 200g, then the mass of orange in the juice would be 50 grams.

You just need to rephrase your question in terms of "mass" instead of "molecular mass":

> Knowing that orange juice has 25% concentration of orange, and knowing mass of juice is 200g, what is mass of orange included in juice?
>
> Assuming that orange is a molecule, am I right that mass of orange in the juice would be 25% x 200g = 50 gram?

Then it makes sense.

Comment: Yes, as Fred says, sometimes it's better to edit the question.